# Swift and prefabs?

Tags: swift, unity-game-engine, sprite-kit

As I'm new to Swift iOS programming and I have question about creating "prefabs"?
I have Unity background and there was something like prefabs that you can instantiate many times. Is there anything similar to that in Swift or Xcode? Especially I'm looking for that in SpriteKit to create copy of SKNode with children

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the closest thing to prefabs would be classes.

you can create a subclass of a SKnode or any other node, for example a SKSpriteNode and then setup that class to do the things you want. Then create an instance of that class.

```
class Box : SKSpriteNode{

    init(){

      //Setup your node the way you want it
       super.init(texture: nil, color: UIColor.red, size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


}


//create instance and add to scene.
let box = Box()
self.addChild(box)
```

you can also setup a node and then use the copy function to copy this node along with its children.

```
let block1 = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.red, size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
let child = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.blue, size: CGSize(width: 25, height: 25))
block1.addChild(child)


let copy = block1.copy() as! SKSpriteNode
addChild(copy)
```

Comment: It works! I tried that approach before but it wasn't working for some reason. Thank you so much!

Comment: iirc this doesnt work for nodees with physics bodies (physics bodies doesnt get copied as it should) ... At least it wasnt working in the past, so make sure you double check that. Somebody feel free to correct me if this is not an issue anymore... @galdev